# Style of axes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following two TikZ pictures (see code at bottom). How can I achieve that the style of the axes in the second picture (the function plot) is the same as in the first picture?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
\draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- (7,0);
\draw (8,0) node[below] {$\gamma$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- (0,5) node[left] {$b_{1+\gamma}$};
\draw (2,.1) -- (2,-.1) node[below] {$p(\rho)-1$};
\draw[dashed] (2,0) -- (2,1.8);
\draw[dashed] (0,2) -- (2,2);
\draw (-.1,2) -- (.1,2) node[left] {$b_\#(\rho)\;$};
\draw (6,.1) -- (6,-.1) node[below] {$1$};
\draw (-0.1,1) -- (0.1,1) node[left] {$b_2\;$};
\draw (0,3.5) .. controls (2,1.8) and (3,1.2) .. (6,1);
\draw[dashed] (0,1) -- (6,1);
\fill[color=white] (0,3.5) circle (3pt);
\draw[color=black] (0,3.5) circle (3pt);
\fill[color=black] (0,4.3) circle (3pt) node[left] {$b_\ast$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = 0:1, samples = 100]
    \addplot[color = black]  {pi/(((pi/2)+atan(x/sqrt(1-x^2))*pi/180)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `axis lines=center` to the axis options. You can also add `axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt}` to make the axes go a bit further (by `10pt`), so the plot doesn't touch the arrow tips.

In order to change the arrow tips, you can load `arrows.meta` and then add `-{>}` for a simple arrow tip.

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:1,samples = 100, axis lines=center, axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt,-{>}}, ymin=0.6,ytick={0.8,1,...,2}]
    \addplot[color = black]  {pi/(((pi/2)+atan(x/sqrt(1-x^2))*pi/180)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thx! Is it also possible to let the y axis start at y=0.8, say? Also the style of the arrow at the tip of the axes is a bit different from the other picture ...

Comment: @lpdbw Yes, I'll be editing my answer now. :) Do you want `y` to start at `0.8` or `-0.8`?

Comment: Thx! I want it to start at height 0.8 ...

Comment: @lpdbw See new edit. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, but seems like I do not have this tikz library: can't find file 'tikzlibraryarrow.meta.code.tex' ... I am using texlive (on Ubuntu 14.04) ... is there an easy way to add the library?

Comment: @lpdbw This library has been available for a long time now, how long ago have you updated your packages? Load your Tex Utility and update the packages. It might take a while depending on how many there are to update. **Alternatively**, you can comment out the library command, and replace the arrow tip option with a simple `->`. It will still work, because it's still "backwards" supported.

Comment: Second option worked. Did a new tex installation only 2 months ago ... strange! And I did the complete installation. Also: I added `xlabel=$\rho$, ylabel=$p(\rho)$` but the caption appears at the wrong position!

Comment: @lpdbw Add `\listfiles` to your preamble, then compile. Open the file named `<yourfilename>.log` and check the `tikz.sty` version. It should say `2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)`. Also `pgf.sty` should be almost the same line except the revision will be `1.15`.

Comment: No it says `2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)`

Comment: @lpdbw Yep, then you should definitely update when you have some free time.

Comment: @lpdbw Did you install from the Ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt-get install texlive`)? This is likely to lead to very out of date versions of TeX and packages. You should look on this site for how to install "Vanilla TeXLive"

Comment: Yes, I installed from there :-) I will not continue the update question in this thread because it leads away from the topic but did thx for the hints. However: did you see my question (some comments above) about the labels? I tried to fix it but haven't succeeded yet ...

Comment: @lpdbw Try, `x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,-0.1)},anchor=north west}, y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,1)},anchor=south east},` and fix accordingly. :)

Comment: Thx! That's good!